# TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable (pynput)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pynput

me (and my friend) are making an autockicker, the code i made (whitch works on its own) dose'nt work with her's. i get the error: `TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable` whitch i think is somthing to do with pynput

i have no clue what to try, (i've done the obvious, google)

here is the code where the error is occuring:

```
def clickerstart():  #this functions activates when you press the "start" button in the autocklicker menu      ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
    if clickerlmb == 1: #if you sellected to click the LMB then this block of code whill be run                ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
        for i in range(0, clickertime): #looping for "clickertime" so we get more than 1 second of clicking    ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
            for i in range(0, CPS): #looping for the CPS so we get more than 1 click                           ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
                delay = 1 / CPS #working out the delay from the CPS value                                      ¦
                mouse.press(Button.left) #pressing the LMB...                                                  ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
                time.sleep(int(delay)) #sleeping for the before worked out time                                ¦
                mouse.release(Button.left) #...and releasing it                                                ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
    if clickerrmb == 1: #if you sellected to click the LMB then this block of code whill be run                ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
        for i in range(0, clickertime): #looping for "clickertime" so we get more than 1 second of clicking    ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
            for i in range(0, CPS): #looping for the CPS so we get more than 1 click                           ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
                delay = 1 / CPS #working out the delay from the CPS value                                      ¦
                mouse.press(Button.right) #pressing the RMB...                                                 ¦
#                                                                                                              ¦
                time.sleep(int(delay)) #sleeping for the before worked out time                                ¦
                mouse.release(Button.right) #...and releasing it                                               ¦
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the full traceback.

Comment: I don't know but my wild guess is that you are using `Button` which is a tkinter class for buttons, python is actually calling that buttons and not whatever button you are trying to mean here. Or is this what you want?

Answer (score -1):

It's because you haven't assigned button to anything using f.e. `def button = 2`.

I think that's it. You have to define it.

Comment: I think this answer is partially correct, up to a point(not sure)

Comment: That's not valid Python. `def` is used to define functions.